# how can I position an object at a moving bonehead?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, drivers

I would like to draw a steam locomotive with rotating wheels, driven by a horizontal rod.

Cannot find an Object Constraint to couple an empty to the head of a rotating bone.

The base of a second bone should follow the head of the rotating bone.
The head of the second bone should move lineairly on one axis.
The base of a third bone (the horizontal rod) should be connected to the head of the second bone.

3        2/\
---------/  \1

Comment: Track To or Copy Location allow you to choose between Head or Tail. Could you describe exactly the animation you'd like to have? Do you need to control the whole thing with the rod or with the rotating bones? Do you need an empty or a bone is ok? Please show some pictures

Comment: Consider a steam-engine. I don't have a site to put an image on and link to it. The "3 2/\ ---------/ \1" was an attempt to graphically visualise it.

Comment: Found a way. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LZawZvDV" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LZawZvDV/)

Comment: oh ok, it was not clear what you wanted without any drawing, so maybe give the full answer  ;)

Comment: Solved, by using drivers, see the following tryout:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Nr0y66eo" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Nr0y66eo/) Thnx you all

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell enough but if you just need a basic animation you can do it this way:

- Create a 3 bone armature. Top horizontal bone is parented to right bone.

[image]

- Switch to *Pose* mode, select the left and right bones, open the *N* panel (on the right of your *3D View*) and in *Transform* > *Rotation*, choose the *XYZ Euler* mode instead of *Quaternion*. Create a first pose for those bones, then a second at 180° (on the *Z* axis for me), and in the *Dopesheet* click <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation*. Now your bones rotate indefinitely.

[image]

- Still in *Pose* mode, select the top bone, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraint* and give it a *Track To* constraint (might be a *Copy Location* as well) with the left bone as *Target*, a *Head/Tail* value of 1, *To* > Y, *Spac*e > *Pose Space/Pose Space*. This bone will follow the movement.

[image]

Comment: My Blender version is: version: 2.83 (sub 15), branch: master, commit date: 2020-05-02 11:33, hash: 1623fdb3bc55, type: Release
build date: 2020-05-02, 21:09:59
platform: Windows and I can't find any adjustment where the middle bone tracks to the HEAD of the left bone. The value of Head/Tail has no influence at all. The middle bone always points to the base of the left bone or makes a 90 degree angle with the right bone while rotating.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a hack, but to follow a bone's head, extrude a little placeholder bone from it, and follow the placeholder's tail (whose location coincides with the bonehead in question) instead.

[image] [image]

Comment: Bummer. Can't follow the placeholder's tail, because its origin is in the base of the first bone and can't be moved, or else the first bone is no more rotating as intended. I hoped that, after adding a single bone and choose Object Constraint: Copy Location, I could push the button Head/Tail and so follow the Head instead of the Tail. Changing the Head/Tail slider from 0 to 1 has no effect at all.

Comment: Found a temporary solution for the proposal of moonboots with the help of the proposal of impresso: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8ynWrZVR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8ynWrZVR/)

Comment: Still I encounter two problems.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=0zS5KZGZ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0zS5KZGZ/) See the scripting text in the .blend-file.

Answer (score 0):

Hereby my solution in text.

Imagine a bone with the tail at the centre of a drive wheel of a steam locomotive.
Adding a second drive wheel a simple: add another armature (bone) at a certain distance from the first one in the X-direction.

Then connect those two drive wheels with a connection rod.
I tried to ad another armature (bone) with constraint 'Copy Location' with the second drive wheel as Target.
In the field labeled Bone, I see a bone, just what I wanted.
Problem 1: Changing Head/Tail from 0 to 1 has no effect at all!?!
Thanks to the former help, I clicked in the field and to my surprise I could choose 'Bone'. That's weird in my opinion, why have to select 'Bone' if I already selected a bone as target? Anyhow, this does the trick: Head/Tail to 1 and problem solved.
Adding Constraint 'Track To', target=first drive wheel, Bone=Bone, Up=X, To=Z and scaling to top it off.

Then imagine a piston, moving horizontally backwards and forwards. A primary connecting rod from this piston to the first driving wheel translates this horizontal movement to rotating.
The tip you gave me was to use drivers.
So I designed a formula for the X-location of the piston: -sqrt(4-cos(r)**2)+sin(r), where r is the rotation_euler of the driving wheel and 2 is the length of the connection rod.
Constraint 'Copy Location' for the primary connecting rod to the first driving wheel head and 'Track To' the piston gives me what I wanted.

The formula I came up with at first was -sqrt(4-cos(r)**2)-sin(r), giving me the same result as using the Blender Keep Distance-modifier.